# Tough Series Question - SSS, SCC, C, SC

Tags: letter-sequence

[image]

**Textual version:**

This question is famously asked in many Amazon interviews.

"What comes next in the series
SSS, SCC, C, SC, ?"

**Hint 1:**

> No numbers will help you in this puzzle

**Hint 2:**

> Think of the alphabet

**Hint 3:**

> A = SSS

Comment: may be answer is SSSS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Each set of letters describes the lines used to write the capital letter. A is three **S**traight lines, B is a **S**traight and two **C**urves, and so on. The next letter is E, which has 4 **S**traight lines. The answer is **SSSS**.

Answer (score 6):

**S** stands for *straight line* (*horizontal, vertical or diagonal*)

i guess the **C** for *curve line*

> 3 straight lines to form **A**
>
> 1 straight line plus 2 curves to form **B**
>
> 1 curve for **C**
>
> 1 straight lines plus 1 curve for **D**
>
> 4 straight lines for **E**
>
> answer: **SSSS**

but for this font:

[image]

> **Straight Line Segments can do all the letters :)**

Comment: Those are line segments, not lines.